# Подсчет количества сумм при убавлении или прибавлении на единицу числа "n" m раз

Tags: python, алгоритм

Столкнулся с проблемой во время написания программы. Чтобы понять задачу, легче представить дерево решений. Есть число n, и есть число m. К числу n нужно прибавлять или отнимать единицу m раз.

Например, **n = 3, m = 3**. Тогда результатов будет 3^2. Число n не должно быть также меньше 1. Получаются такие цепочки : *3-2-1-1* или *3-2-3-2* или *3-2-3-4* или *3-4-3-2* и так далее. Необходимо вывести все суммы, которые получаются таким путем.

Никак не могу сообразить, как написать такой код. Пытался хранить цепочки в отдельных листах, а потом получать сумму, но не смог реализовать. Прошу помочь на языке **Python**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему 3-2-1-1?

Comment: Там где у вас `-` между числами, это ведь не вычитание? Это просто список длины `m`, первое число в списке `n`, соседние числа отличаются не более чем на единицу, все числа больше нуля. Так? Надо наделать таких списков, для каждого найти его сумму. Вывести множество все таких сумм (каждая сумма только один раз). Так?

Comment: Почему в вашем примере нет цепочки `3,3,3,3`? Какое правило её запрещает? Почему тогда можно `3,2,1,1`? На него это правило не действует?

Comment: По сути, количество сумм не зависит от n, а только от m... И, если не ошибаюсь, оно просто равно m+1.

Comment: Там какое-то отражение от единицы.

Comment: В моей цепочке 3,2,1,1 присутствует второй раз единица, так как число, полученное от n не должно быть меньше единицы, то есть первый раз операция пропускается, а дальше прибавляется единица и число становится равно двойке. Но можно использовать и вариант сразу 3-2-1-2. Цепочка 3,3,3,3 не может быть, так как каждый раз нужно отнимать или прибавлять единицу от полученного числа.

Comment: Покажите место в условии, где написано "число, полученное от n не должно быть меньше единицы"? А когда вам решат очередную задачу, выяснится, что кроме 1, можно еще и 2 вычитать, а прибавлять 3? Научитесь точно формулировать условие задания!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что начались "уточнения" вопроса, которых нет в условии, т.е. задание поставлено некорректно.

Comment: @Sinka, сейчас ваш вопрос закроют. Не расстраивайтесь. Надо исправить постановку задачи так что бы ни у кого не было вопросов и разночтений. После этого вопрос откроют обратно, надеюсь. Задача, сама по себе, интересная. С удовольствием её решу.

Comment: Однако, открывать вопрос снова не имеет разумного смысла, ответ, предоставленный @Harry удовлетворяет, я смогу адаптировать его под свою задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, так:

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())

for i in range(0,m+1):
    print(n - m + 2*i)
```

Ваша же картинка для n = m = 3 должна иметь вид:

```
                3
               / \
              2   4
             / \ / \
            1   3   5
           / \ / \ / \
          0   2   4   6
```

Думаю, продление картинки (и выводы из нее :)) очевидны...